# Column specific styles for Isotope masonry layout mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I have an isotope gallery with a masonry layout:

https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/owVqmy

JS:

```
$('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    layoutMode: 'masonry'
});
```

CSS:

```
.grid-item {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Which basically splits the gallery into two columns. Is there any way to add first / second column specific styles in the case? I.e. I want all images from the first columnd to have a green border, and images from the second column - a red one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don’t think this will work in all cases, but you could try using `.grid-item:nth-child(even) { border-color: red }`. If that isn’t sufficient, you will need to use JS to iterate over each item and check its left offset to determine if it's in the left or right column, then add a class.

Comment: @TedWhitehead, odd / even won't work, you are right (this is a mansory layout after all). Seems like it's only JS left!

Comment: Yeah, I think that’s your best bet. Just make sure to re-run the JS after each time Masonry updates https://masonry.desandro.com/events.html#layoutcomplete

Comment: @TedWhitehead, Denialos in the answer below suggested to add a class depending on the `left` value (say first columnd elements have it les that 1%). Is there a way to hook up into Isotope events to add a class there instead of doing calculations on layout change, what do you think?

Comment: @TedWhitehead, selector like `.grid-item[style*="left: 0;"]` did the trick without JS. Thansk!

Comment: Oh, nice! Good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be possible to style first column elements with CSS:

```
.grid-item[style*="left: 0;"] {
    border-color: green;
}
```

taken that the left column item have a left property set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the order of the `.grid` element's children is going to stay the same, you can solve this by applying a CSS selector for the `.grid` className like below:

```
.grid > div:nth-of-type(odd) { 
    border: 1px solid green; 
}

.grid > div:nth-of-type(even) { 
    border: 1px solid red; 
}
```

Notice that I'm using `odd` and `even` values for `nth-of-type` to get the desirable result.

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work. Otherwise why would I need a masonry layout? :-)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Perhaps there's a way to add a custom className for each masonry element depending on some condition? Like, if your block has a `left` coord of zero, it should be in the first column. This way, it could have a specific className.

Assuming masonry updates this on resize too, you could have a clean solution with CSS anyways. Not a big user of Masonry myself, just wondering here. :)